# vim's tab length is different for .py files

Tags: python, vim, indentation

In my `~/.vimrc` I set tab to me 2 spaces long

```
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
```

However when I open a `.py` file, tabs are 4 spaces long. I don't have specific configuration for python files. `~/.vim/after` is empty and searching for `py` doesn't raise any suspect lines.

Have you ever experienced that? How to solve such a behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean to say that when you open an _existing_ Python file (which probably already has 4-spaces)? Vim won't automatically reindent to your preferred setting if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, vim display `\t` as 4 spaces both when I open an existing file (with tabs for indentation) and when I create a new file with a `.py` extention

Comment: Note, you can also do `let g:python_recommended_style = 0` to override the default `ftplugin/python.vim`  (it only keeps default tabs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s defined in the general Python filetype plugin file (`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`):

```
" As suggested by PEP8.
setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
```

It should be so in order to conform with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

---

@Carpetsmoker adds:

There is [a discussion about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_dev/Martin$20Tournoij/vim_dev/idpI6hOprow/1QZED336SmYJ) on the vim-dev@ list.

You can reset this using this in your `~/.vimrc`; for example:

```
aug python
    " ftype/python.vim overwrites this
    au FileType python setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 noexpandtab
aug end
```

Or by adding config settings in `$HOME/.vim/after`.

Comment: Why did you remove my edits? This seems like useful information to me? I originally made my own answer, but having all information in a single answer seemed better, because that reduces the amount of "noise" & duplicate information.

Comment: I’m not sure about the etiquette here, but I think the edit is not fully in accord with the ‘how to edit’ section in the editing screen (► fix grammatical or spelling errors ► clarify meaning without changing it ► correct minor mistakes ► add related resources or links ► always respect the original author): it is more than just fixing grammatical or spelling errors, clarifying meaning without changing it or correcting minor mistakes; it do not add (external) resources or links; and it added things I didn’t write under my name without my prior agreement.

Comment: I will re-edit it in a moment; please say if the new wording is OK with you.

Comment: Well, sometimes a second answer just doesn't add enough information to warrant a new answer; your answer sits on top by virtue of being marked as accepted, my answer with the extra information somewhere below that ... It's generally accepted that an edit in these cases is fine, this makes the site a lot better for people who end up here through an internet search, and such... You didn't have to mark it as community wiki, btw ;-)

Comment: This happens to work for me, but I would like to find the specific config that is taking hold and saying "My name is Python and I get to use special vim config props that I won't tell you about"

Answer (score 2):

likely you have some plugin installed to ease your python editing, and those plugin re-set some vim options.

You can find out by:

- open one py file, verify if tabstop/shiftwidth is `4`
- then run command: `:verbose set ts` and `:verbose set sw`

You can see where the options were set last time.

Comment: that worked. The values where overiden in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim` as pointed out my Júda Ronén