# Spf13 VIM tab indentation

Tags: python, vim, spf13vim

I'm trying to set the intendation for Spf13 VIM to tabs. According to the docs this should be done in `~/.vimrc.local`. I've created that file and put the following content there:

```
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

I also tried deleting all the files in `~/.vimviews/`. But it doesn't work. It still uses spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: It's probably set by a filetype plugin. Check `:verbose set et?` where this got set.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you. Post it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Filetype plugins* (from `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/` or `~/.vim/ftplugin`) are executed (when you have `:filetype plugin on`, a common setting), and some of those override the global indent settings. You can check and find the culprit via

```
:verbose set et?
```

To override the ftplugin's settings, you can put corresponding antidote `:setlocal noexpandtab` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something very similar to this question I’ve answer a moment ago… [vim's tab length is different for .py files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403413/vims-tab-length-is-different-for-py-files).

Comment: It's different than mine. Not the same path as the output of @Ingo Karkat command was.

Comment: Aren’t your settings overridden by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`?

Comment: So great; that’s what matters… ☺